# Print characters in brainfuck

Tags: input, char, brainfuck

I am new to this language and i am building brainfuck interpreter in scala i am facing one problem what should i print if the value at memory index is greater than 127 ? 
what a real brainfuck interpreter print if value is greater than 127?
for eg
memory[index]=178
when "." (print command) is called what should a brainfuck iterpreter  print ?
my compiled some codes on ideone.com but it showing runtime error .
for follwing code:

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++[+.<-]

Answer (score 3):

The [original implementation](http://main.aminet.net/dev/lang/brainfuck-2.lha) for `.` just calls `putchar()` with whatever `unsigned char` value is in the cell:

```
...
case '.': putchar(a[p]); fflush(stdout); break;
...
```

This means how characters 128-255 show up depends on what encoding your terminal uses. If I set mine to [CP437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), characters 32-255 look like this:

[image: example output]

In your case, Scala's `toChar` method on numbers sounds like it should do what you want; also, maybe ideone is just weird about printing extended ASCII.

Comment: yes @nooodl ideone showing runtime error , may be not support these characters. anyway thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no thorough language specification, but in most interpreters incrementing a cell which holds its maximal value (with the + command) will bring it to its minimal value and vice verse.